# How to pass down values in a list to a Controller in C# after the values in the view are changed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, foreach, view, controller

I have a viewmodel which contains data and is loaded in my view. To show the data in the HTML, I used some @foreach loops.

Now the page contains values from the viewmodel. For example, if the viewmodel contains 10 items, all 10 items are loaded through @foreach loops in the html.

After evertyhing is loaded, my javascript code checks how many items there are and splits the items to 2 different containers if certain conditions are met.

To give more color to the sketch:

The items are deliverables. Each deliverable has an address where it need to be delivered to. These addresses will be marked as deliverypoints on the map. The map is 1 container. So for example if I have 10 items there will be 10 marks on the map. The javascript calculates the distance and travel time between these marks. If the total deliverytime exceed 8 hours (a workday) then it extracts some items from the total itempool untill the total deliverytime in that specific container is under the 8 hours. The remainder of the deliverables will be put in another map (container).

**Question**

How can I post these 2 newly made containers including the items to my controller?

So what I need is is something like this:

```
public ActionResult RetrieveContainerIncludingItems(List<ExampleModel> Containers)
```

This list should contain its items.

This is my View Code:

```
<div class="content-container map-outer">
   <div class="head">Transport</div>
   <div class="content">
      <div class="date-container">
      </div>
      <div class="map-inner">
         <div class="route-container">
            <div class="route-header">
               <div class="truck-container">
                  <span class="truck-number">1</span>
               </div>
               <div class="starting-time-container">Starttime: <span class="starting-time">8:00</span></div>
               <div class="data-right">
                  <span class="vehicle-number">XR-VR-95</span>
                  <span class="driver-name">Eric Peterson</span>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="route-inner">
               <!------------------------------------------>
               @{var counter = 0;}
               @foreach (var item in Model.TransportPlannerModels)
               {
               counter++;
               string status = (item.Status == "Deliver") ? "route-item drop-off" : "route-item pick-up";
               <div class="@status">
                  <div class="item-header">
                     <div class="item-order-container">
                        <span class="item-order">@counter</span>
                     </div>
                     <div class="location-type-container">
                        <span class="location-type">@item.Status</span>
                     </div>
                     <div class="location-address-container">
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.Firstname)
                        <span class="location-address">@item.Firstname @item.LastName - @item.StreetName @item.Housenumber , @item.ZipCode <br/> @item.City</span>
                     </div>
                     <div class="icon-container">
                        <span class="icon icon-plus">+</span>
                        <span class="icon icon-minus">-</span>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item-center">
                     <div class="technical-info">
                        <span class="lat"></span>
                        <span class="lng"></span>
                        <span class="place_id"></span>
                     </div>
                     <div class="info-container">
                        <div class="order-number-container center-option-container">
                           <span class="center-bold">Ordernumber</span>
                           <span class="center-colon">:</span>
                           <span class="center-data order-number">@counter</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="name-container center-option-container">
                           <span class="center-bold">Name</span>
                           <span class="center-colon">:</span>
                           <span class="center-data name">@item.Firstname @item.LastName</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="address-container center-option-container">
                           <span class="center-bold">Address</span>
                           <span class="center-colon">:</span>
                           <span class="center-data address">@item.StreetName @item.Housenumber, @item.ZipCode @item.City</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="kilometers-container center-option-container">
                           <span class="center-bold">Amount<br />kilometers</span>
                           <span class="center-colon">:</span>
                           <span class="center-data kilometers">50 km</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="products-container center-option-container">
                           <span class="center-bold">Products</span>
                           <span class="center-colon">:</span>
                           <span class="center-data products">
                              <ul>
                                 @foreach (var product in item.ProductTitles)
                                 {
                                 <li>@product.Key x @product.Value</li>
                                 }
                              </ul>
                           </span>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="marker-container">
                        <span class="marker-outer">
                        <span class="marker-number">@counter</span>
                        </span>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item-bottom">
                     <div class="dots-container">
                        <span class="dot"></span>
                        <span class="dot"></span>
                        <span class="dot"></span>
                     </div>
                     <div class="bottom-flex">
                        <p>
                           Estimated traveltime: <span class="calculated-time">39min</span> <span class="dash">-</span><br /> Afstand: <span class="calculated-kilometers">51,8km</span>
                        </p>
                        <p><span class="estimated-time"></span></p>
                     </div>
                     <!------------------------------------------>
                  </div>
               </div>
               }
            </div>
            <div class="total-container">
               <p><span class="bold">Total Traveltime: </span><span class="total-time">5:30</span><span class="bold">Kilometers: </span><span class="total-km">262,8km</span></p>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div id="mapContainer0" class="map-container"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The javascript you describe looks like business logic that should be server side. Depending on your user base (if they are not totally trusted), you should consider doing that logic on the server.

Comment: dont pay attention to the static values in the code. its just an example. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: make your second container a partial view. 
use Action that will accept, for example a list of item ids to be moved to a second container and load it with Ajax. (if i correctly get your question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("div .map-inner").each(function(index, element) {
var AllOrderItems = new Array();

$($(this).find('.route-item')).each(function(index, element) {
    AllOrderItems.push($(this).find('.orderItemID').val());
})

var MapContainer = {
    DriverName: $(this).find('.driver-name').text(),
    TotalDistance: $(this).find('.total-km').text(),
    TotalTime: $(this).find('.total-time').text(),
    LicensePlate: $(this).find('.vehicle-number').text(),
    OrderItems: AllOrderItems
}
AllMaps.push(MapContainer);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**View**

```
<div id="divPartial2">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
        var ActionParams = new Object();
        ActionParams.ItemIds= ...;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(ActionParams),
            contentType: "application/json",
            datatype: "html",
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $("#divPartial2").html(data);
            },
        });
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult FilteredItems(List<int> itemIds)
    {
        //get only items for second container
        return PartialView("Container");
    }
```